# active or disactive dropdown list based on another dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i have 3 drop down list in my contact form which i active or disactive two of them with first drop down list. till today my first drop down had two options and when i selected rent,it made price range disactive automatically and when i selected sell,it made rent range drop down disactive automatically. today i decided to add one more option to first drop down "presell" now i want to disactive rent range and active price range when i select this option too exactly like sell option. but i can not mange it. please help me? thank you

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p dir="rtl"><select id="select" name="case" style="width: 110px;">
      <option  selected="selected" value="red">sell</option>
      <option  value="green">rent</option>
      <option  value="blue">presell</option>
      </select></p>
    <p dir="rtl"><select name="pricerange" class="myclass1" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="" >please select</option>
      <option value="1" >A</option>
      <option value="2" >B</option>
      <option value="3" >C</option>
      </select></p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#select').change(function(){
        $('.myclass1').attr('disabled',$(this).val() === 'green');
      });
    </script>
    <p dir="rtl"><select name="rentrange" class="myclass2" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="" >please select</option>
      <option value="4" >AA</option>
      <option value="5" >BB</option>
      <option value="6" >CC</option>
      </select></p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#select').change(function(){
        $('.myclass2').attr('disabled',$(this).val() === 'red');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another equation with 'or' operater (||) to the attribute condition.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <head>
      <body>
         <p dir="rtl"><select id="select" name="case" style="width: 110px;">
  <option  selected="selected" value="red">sell</option>
  <option  value="green">rent</option>
    <option  value="blue">presell</option>
</select></p>
         <p dir="rtl"><select name="pricerange" class="myclass1" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
<option value="" >please select</option>
<option value="1" >A</option>
<option value="2" >B</option>
<option value="3" >C</option>
</select></p>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#select').change(function(){
  $('.myclass1').attr('disabled',$(this).val() === 'green');
        });
    </script>
         <p dir="rtl"><select name="rentrange" class="myclass2" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
<option value="" >please select</option>
<option value="4" >AA</option>
<option value="5" >BB</option>
<option value="6" >CC</option>
</select></p>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#select').change(function(){
  $('.myclass2').attr('disabled',
                $(this).val() === 'red' || $(this).val() === 'blue' );
        });
    </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the value of the `#select` dropdown is **or** red **or** blue. using this code:

```
var val = $(this).val();
$('.myclass2').attr('disabled',val === 'red' || val == 'blue');
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p dir="rtl"><select id="select" name="case" style="width: 110px;">
      <option  selected="selected" value="red">sell</option>
      <option  value="green">rent</option>
      <option  value="blue">presell</option>
      </select></p>
    <p dir="rtl"><select name="pricerange" class="myclass1" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="" >please select</option>
      <option value="1" >A</option>
      <option value="2" >B</option>
      <option value="3" >C</option>
      </select></p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#select').change(function(){
        $('.myclass1').attr('disabled',$(this).val() === 'green');
      });
    </script>
    <p dir="rtl"><select name="rentrange" class="myclass2" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="" >please select</option>
      <option value="4" >AA</option>
      <option value="5" >BB</option>
      <option value="6" >CC</option>
      </select></p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#select').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('.myclass2').attr('disabled',val === 'red' || val == 'blue');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answering but in this case my rent range dropdown is always disactive no matter  what i select

Comment: @user6362236 When you say `rent dropdown` do you mean the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery in array function

$('.myclass2').attr('disabled', $.inArray(val, ['blue','red']));

```html
<html>

<head>

  <head>

    <body>
      <p dir="rtl">
        <select id="select" name="case" style="width: 110px;">
          <option selected="selected" value="red">sell</option>
          <option value="green">rent</option>
          <option value="blue">presell</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p dir="rtl">
        <select name="pricerange" class="myclass1" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="">please select</option>
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $('#select').change(function() {
          $('.myclass1').attr('disabled', $(this).val() === 'green');
        });
      </script>
      <p dir="rtl">
        <select name="rentrange" class="myclass2" style="width: 110px;" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="">please select</option>
          <option value="4">AA</option>
          <option value="5">BB</option>
          <option value="6">CC</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $('#select').change(function() {
          var val = $(this).val();
          $('.myclass2').attr('disabled', $.inArray(val, ['blue','red']));
        });
      </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answering in but in this case my rent range dropdown disactive always